# How can I shorthand checking for undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have code like this:

```
var process = function(next){
    //do stuff
    if(typeof next != 'undefined') { next(a, b, c, d, e); }

}
```

I'm so sick of typing `typeof` everywhere. Is there a global function I can write that handles checking for undefined as well as all the arguments?

For example:

```
_call = function(next){
    if(typeof next != 'undefined') next();
};
```

The above example doesn't work, by the way. Because node throws an error when I do this:

```
_call(next('hello', 'world')); //ERROR! next is undefined
```

So maybe I can do this?

```
_call(next, argument1, argument2, ... )
```

Comment: Actually you shouldn't be checking for it not to be `undefined`, you should be checking for it to be `function`.

Comment: You're looking for `function _call(fn, ...args) { if (typeof fn == "function") return fn(...args); }` (or `fn.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))` in ES5)

Comment: @Bergi yes that's what I want. Can you write it as an official answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a builtin function that handles checking for undefined as well as all the arguments?

No, but you can write one yourself.

> So maybe I can do this? `_call(next, argument1, argument2, ... )`

Yes:

```
function _call(fn, ...args) {
    if (typeof fn == "function") return fn(...args);
}
```

(using ES6 rest & spread syntax, in ES5 it would be `fn.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)`)

Comment: @Kaiido: Oops, yeah, totally right. I somehow skipped over that part. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack but you might be able to use default arguments

```
(function(next=()=>{}){
    //do stuff
    next(a, b, c, d, e); 
})();
```

So if it is not called with an argument, next will be an empty function that doesn't do anything

Comment: I wouldn't call that a hack, it's a proper solution! You can also use a `function noop() {}` so that you don't have to repeat the arrow function expression (and that no new function is created on every call).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `typeof` at all. The terminology in this case is slightly strange but here is the explanation:

```
var v; // initialize variable v
if (v) {} // works although v has type "undefined"
if (notInitialized) {} // ReferenceError: notDefined is not defined
```

And it is the same when you have a function with parameters. The arguments are *always* initialized but might have the type `undefined`.

As a result, you can use either

```
var process = function(next){
    //do stuff
    if (next) { next(a, b, c, d, e); }
}
```

or even

```
var process = function(next){
    next && next(a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

However, before actually calling `next` it might be a good approach to check whether it is actually a function.

If you are using ES6, you might also be able to use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in case these work with your use case.

Comment: I'd like to check if it's undefined. Sometimes, people simply call `process()` and omit the `next`

Comment: @TIMEX `if (next)` checks for values that are not falsy (including false, undefined, null, 0, '').

Answer (score 0):

It should be undefined and throws an error. Because you call a function named `next` and pass as argument to `_call`.

This is the right one :

```
_call(function('hello', 'world'){//do dtuff});
```

And

```
_call = function(next){
    if(typeof next === 'function') next();
};
```

Comment: You misunderstand my use case. `next` is a variable that is passed around.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
_call = function(next){
    if(next && next != 'undefined' && next != 'null') next();
};
```

Comment: undefined != 'undefined'

Comment: if(next) will return false for next==undefined || next==null suppose by chance if they converted to string we need to check 'null' and 'undefined' in string operation

Comment: That's a heavy assumption. What if "undefined" is a valid input?

Comment: then simply check for if(next) it will return false for null and undefined if user provide 'null' ,'undefined' as a valid input

Comment: This will still crash if `next` is undefined in the first place and you do `_call(next(1, 2, 3))`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".